# Breaks the flexbox layout when I wrapped the divs with <a>

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to make a div within a flex container a clickable link.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  background: silver;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container flex_container">
    <div class="box">link1</div>
    <div class="box">link2</div>
    <div class="box">link3</div>
    <div class="box">link4</div>
    <a href="example.com"><div class="box">link5</div></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Im trying to make the 4 divs in the container div clickable links. Putting a hyperlink around them as such: `<a href="example.com"><div class="box">link</div></a>`destroys the layout of the container.

Basically, Im trying to make a top menu bar, with 4 boxes, covering the whole width of the screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Https://codepen.io/arxopxib/pen/MWKPJxg, I hope it help ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change the `div` to a `<a>` like this

```css
.container{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.flex_container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box{
  background: silver;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container flex_container">
    <a href="#" class="box">link1</a>
    <a href="#" class="box">link2</a>
    <a href="#" class="box">link3</a>
    <a href="#" class="box">link4</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :) could you accept my answer if it fixed your problem? :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set `display: contents` for `.flex_container>a`

> **contents**
>
> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
> pseudo-elements still generate boxes and text runs as normal. For the
> purposes of box generation and layout, the element must be treated as
> if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents (including
> both its source-document children and its pseudo-elements, such as
> ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, which are generated before/after
> the element’s children as normal).
> <sup>[Ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents)</sup>

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  background: silver;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex_container>a {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container flex_container">
    <div class="box">link1</div>
    <div class="box">link2</div>
    <div class="box">link3</div>
    <div class="box">link4</div>
    <a href="example.com">
      <div class="box">link5</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Https://codepen.io/arxopxib/pen/MWKPJxg, I hope it help ^_^

Comment: @AhmedAlduri I'm not the who asked the question.

Comment: Sorry iam new here

Comment: hey, I appreciate the answer but I'm really having a hard time following... really. way beyond my understanding what you wrote. but thanks.

Comment: I fixed it for now just by changing <div> to <a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use *css direct child*
Replace `.box {/*css*/}` by `.flex_container>.box, .flex_container>a {/*css*/}` or `.flex_container>* {/*css*/}`